# Selecting dsPIC33FJ programming pins

Tags: pic, programmer

I'm getting ready to print up a board for a project using a dsPIC33FJ256GP710A.  I've currently got it running on a EasyPic Fusion devboard.

I see that there are a bunch of pairs of PGED's and PGEC's available to choose from for layout convenience.  I also see that there are config bits that need to be set for which ones you pick.

So, lets say I plan to program the dsPIC on board, using PCED3 and PGEC3.  Until I set the config bits, how will the chip know that that's where the programmer will live?  How can I set the config bits until the chip knows where to look for the programmer?  I suspect that the chip will program from any programming port pair, but will only debug from the configured pair.  That said, I've been searching data sheet which sent me to the Family programming reference, http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70152c.pdf, and I can't satisfy myself that if I try to get the answer by setting the programming ports to something other than what the built-in programmer is tied to that I won't brick my $25 daughterboard with the PIC on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its doesn't make any difference until you start debugging.  However, always review the errata for your particular chip to be sure that all pairs work.  There are a handful of MC parts where one pair won't work.

I didn't see anything in the errata, but check anyway.

Comment: Thanks.  Nothing in the errata, but absolutely right to check.  I just set the programming pins to an unused pair, and the chip still programs, so they are all active, just like you said.  Is this info on all the programming pins being active for programming in any of the data sheets?  I love to learn where the info in these long sheets is.

Comment: Some of this information is probably inferred rather than explicitly stated anywhere.  In the Pic32mx5xx datasheet, there is a little information under ISCP pins, but nothing that directly says all pins are equal.